# Android-x86 froyo mouse

Tags: linux, terminal, kernel, android-x86

I am working with [Android 2.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Froyo) x86 (Froyo).

After entering into the console, I issued a *[ps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ps_(Unix))* command and got the <kbd>Kpsmoused</kbd> [daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)). What is it?

<kbd>USER</kbd> <kbd>PID</kbd> <kbd>PPID</kbd> <kbd>VSIZE</kbd> <kbd>RSS</kbd> <kbd>WCHAN</kbd> <kbd>PC</kbd> <kbd>NAME</kbd>
`root 1116 0 0 c103ea42 00000000 S kpsmoused`

Answer (score 0):

It is the PS/2 mouse driver. See *[PS/2 interface and protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_(computing)#PS.2F2_interface_and_protocol)* and http://www.computer-engineering.org/ps2mouse/.

Comment: The second link is broken (the whole www.computer-engineering.org site is broken (the domain expired)). Some alternatives are (essentially the ***same content by the same author***, but slightly different titles and modification dates): *[The PS/2 Mouse/Keyboard Protocol](https://www.avrfreaks.net/sites/default/files/PS2%20Keyboard.pdf)* (2003-05-09), *[The PS/2 Keyboard Interface](http://www-ug.eecg.toronto.edu/msl/nios_devices/datasheets/PS2%20Keyboard%20Protocol.htm)* (2003-04-01), and *[The AT-PS/2 Keyboard Interface](https://www.tayloredge.com/reference/Interface/atkeyboard.pdf)* (2001).